# Group by part of varchar field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a SQL table representing a stock of product. Let's say it looks like this

```
id - product - quantity
------------------------
1 -  water 1L  - 2
2 -  Coke 1L   - 3
3 -  water 5L  - 7
4 -  water 10L - 1
5 -  Coke 2L   - 3
```

I want to know how many bottle I have in stock, is it possible to do so without adding a column with the type of product and get a result like

```
water - sum(quantity)
Coke  - sum(quantity)
```

Comment: instead of a needed column you should have a hole table for it that references to the neede column, also one for sizes and possibly for type bottle or can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data format for product column is fixed throughout the table(*all product names are composed of one word except for Liter portion*), then use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(product,' ',1) AS product_common_def , SUM(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY product_common_def
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5647036296ad038e0043361c31734ad3)</kbd>